# Degenerate null space of linear map: what properties?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, matrix-equations, matrix-rank

Suppose $A$ is an $m\times n$ matrix. Solve the homogeneous system of linear equations $Ax=0$. We know that,

1. $x$ has nonzero solution, if and only if $\text{rank}(A)<n$.
2. $\#$ free parameters of $x$ = $\text{dim}(\text{null}(A))$ = $n-\text{rank}(A)$.

Note that here **"nonzero"** means **"not all entries of $x$ are zero"**. But for a nonzero $x$, there is a case where **some entries of $x$ must always be zero**. For example,
$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 
\end{bmatrix},$$then the first entry of $x$ must always be zero. In other words, the null space of $A$, which should be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$, is actually a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$. Seeing from the basis of $\text{null}(A)$, then some dimension of these vector(s) is always zero.

I call this the **"degenerated null space"**. I was wondering if there is any particular properties about it, e.g. what is the iff condition for a matrix $A$ s.t. $\text{null}(A)$ is degenerated? What is the relationship between $A$ and $A'$, the submatrix of $A$ which deletes columns w.r.t. always-zero dimension?

Also looking for related materials. Would really appreciate it if you could provide some links, materials about it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your kernel is "degenerated" iff there is some $e_i$ so that $e_i$ is orthogonal to the kernel. But as the kernel is defined to be everything that is orthogonal to the rows of $A$ we get that this is the case iff $e_i$ is in the space spanned by the rows of $A$. For example in your case
$$ e_1 = 2(1,1,1) - (1,2,2)$$
So the kernel is degenerated in the $i$-th coordinate iff
$$ xA = e_i $$
has a solution.

Then $A$ and $A'$ are basically the same matrix, just with some $0$-columns removes. Your question here is quite broad, so I’m not sure what relationship you’re interested in. But note that the kernel of $A$ is isometrically isomorphic to some $\mathbb R^k$ where $k$ is the dimension of the kernel anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What is the exact definition of $e_i$, given $A$ and $i$?

Comment: About $A$ and $A'$: in my example $A'= \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 2 & 2 \end{bmatrix} $, which deletes the first column. Then $\text{null}(A)$ and $\text{null}(A')$ are the same, with adding one zero solution. (is that true?) I am interested in properties like this, relationships between $A,A'$, or between $\text{null}(A),\text{null}(A')$.

Comment: @graphitump Ah, I think I misunderstood what $A'$ should be. I suppose $A'$ is the matrix where all degenerate columns are removed. Generally if you remove a column (wlog the last one) of a matrix $A$ then if $A'x' = 0$ then $Ax=0$ for $x=(x',0)$. So the kernel of $A'$ is mapped into the kernel of $A$ by $x\mapsto (x,0)$. Conversely if $x$ is in the kernel of $A$ and $x=(x',0)$ then $x'$ is in the kernel of $A'$. So this implies that by removing $d$ degenerate columns the kenel of $A'$ is isomorphic to the kernel of $A$ by adding $0$s.